# How to prove that the area of quadrilateral $EHFG$ is equal to the sum of the areas of triangles $AGB$ and $DHC$?

Tags: geometry, proof-explanation

Let $ABCD$ be a convex quadrilateral. Points $E$ and $F$ are midpoints of sides $\overline{AD}$ and $\overline{BC}$, respectively. Point $G$ is the intersection of lines $AF$ and $BE$, and point $H$ is the intersection of lines $DF$ and $CE$, respectively. Prove the area of quadrilateral $EHFG$ is equal to the sum of areas of triangles $\triangle AGB$ and $\triangle DHC$.

[image: Image for reference]

Comment: HINT. The distance of $E$ from line $CD$ is the average of the distances of $A$ and $B$ from the same line.

Comment: kindly include ur attempt

Comment: @Aretino ok thanks. now I get it.

Answer (score 0):

When $[ABC]$ is area of triangle $\Delta ABC$, then we have to show
$$ [ABG] + [ CDH] =[EFG] + [EFH] $$

which is equivalent to
$$ ([ABG] + [BFG])+([ CDH] +[CFH])=([EFG] + [BFG])+
( [EFH] +[CFH] )\ (1)$$

Hence **$A,\ E,\ D$ has a height $H,\ \frac{H+h}{2},\ h$ from a line
segment $[BC]$**, then $$  ([ABG] + [BFG])+([ CDH] +[CFH]) =
\frac{1}{2} Hy +\frac{1}{2} hy\ (2) $$

$$([EFG] + [BFG])+
( [EFH] +[CFH] ) = \frac{1}{2} \frac{H+h}{2}y + \frac{1}{2}
\frac{H+h}{2}y\ (3) $$ Hence $(2),\ (3)$ gives $(1)$